# TFS Check In comment change log

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there logging to view check in comment changes, meaning, if someone makes a TFS check in, then later 'someone' updates the comment. Is there a log to tell me who made the change and what the old/new comments were/are???

Comment: Assuming you mean for TFVC.  Are you cloud or on-premise?

Comment: yes...on premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, we **do not have this kind of log** which could tell you who made the change and the old comments were.

The only users who can modify the comments that are associated with a changeset are **the users who created the changeset** or **a user who has the Revise other user's changes global permission**.

For example, a user without [Edit project-level information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-permissions)  permission. He will not be able to change other user's changeset comment. The save button will get disabled.

You can get there by VS -> Team -> Team project Settings -> Security. This will also help you narrow down the scope and prevent others to do this  freely.